# Regex removing anything that is not a 14-digit number followed with space

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to invert this expression: `([0-9]{14} )`, 
so all 14 digit numbers followed by a space.

I looked everywhere, and it seems that the best way should be using **negative lookahead**.
But when I try apply `q(?!u)` to my case >> `(?!([0-9]{14} ))`, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

I will appreaciate any advice, thank you.

The point is to remove everything that is not a 14-digit chunk of text while preserving those 14-digit chunks.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are doing? What does *negate* mean in the context of your question?  Remove everything that does not match `([0-9]{14} )`? Highlight everything that does not match it? Just fetch those substrings that do not match it? Please be specific. See [`[0-9]{14} (*SKIP)(?!)|(?:(?![0-9]{14} ).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/fP4xH4/1). Or the [`[0-9]{14} |(.)` -> `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/fP4xH4/2). What is the language, BTW?

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to select everything what is not a 14-digit number followed by a space.
So everything what doesnt match to `([0-9]{14} )` this.

I am not using any special language, just notepad++ or just any real-time regExps.

Comment: Ok, notepad++ means a Boost library. Are you just search for that text, or you want to remove it? What is the final goal? If you want to delete everything else, just use `(\b\d{14} )|.` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Hi,
thank you and sorry - I don't have time everytime.

That is exactly it! :)
Thank you so much!

Can you please also explain why does the expressions look like they do?

Comment: I have written an answer, please check and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete text other than 14 digits followed with a space, use `(\b\d{14} )|.` and replace with `$1`.

The pattern matches and *captures*  (we can refer to the text captured with a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement pattern) the 14-digit chunks and then a space as whole word due to [`\b` (a word boundary)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). If this text is not found, any character other than a newline is matched with `.` and is not captured (we cannot refer to it with a backreference).

Thus, when we replace with a backreference `$1`, we just restore the matched 14 digit chunk with a space.

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xY2pC8/1).

[image]

To get the cleaner view, remove all empty lines: `Edit` > `Line Operations` > `Remove Empty Lines`.

Comment: If there can be several consecutive 14-digit chunks followed with a space, just use a `$1|` replacement pattern, and after the first search and replace  described above, run a second post-processing operation replacing `|` with a newline `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*[0-9]{14} )
```

- Make sure you use start anchor `^`
- Also important to use `.*` before your pattern to disallow this anywhere in input

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much, but unfortunetly, it's not working.

Comment: What is your input string?