# gsub R extract numeric from string

Tags: regex, r

I have this input character:
    `($3.24)`
I would like to get 
    `3.24`
I tried:

```
test <- c("($3.24)")
aa <- gsub("[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+", '\\1', test)
```

What is the replacement `\\1` for?

Comment: it doesn't do anything since there is not a capture group in `pattern`. changing your code slightly to `gsub("([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+)|.", '\\1', test)` will give your desired result

Comment: @rawr: Exactly my approach for a similar  Notepad++ [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696455/regex-removing-anything-that-is-not-a-14-digit-number-followed-with-space/36763298#36763298). Match what you do not need, and match and *capture* what you need to keep. [The Best Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `\\1` means whatever was in the first capture group in the regular expression.  A capture group is defined by a closure (parentheses), but since you didn't define anything meaningful you are not getting the result you wanted.

Here is a correct use of `gsub()` to get what you wanted:

```
> gsub("\\(\\$([0-9]+\\.+[0-9]+)\\)", "\\1", "($3.24)")
[1] "3.24"
```

The regular expression being used here is:

```
\(\$([0-9]+\.+[0-9]+)\)
```

The *capture group* is `([0-9]+\.+[0-9]+)`, which is anything coming in between `($` and the closing parenthesis `)`, which is a number possibly containing a single decimal point.  Using `gsub()` will then replace `test` with whatever was capture, in this case `3.24`.

You can explore this regular expression here:

## Regex101

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of function `extract_numeric` from package `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
test <- c("($3.24)")
extract_numeric(test)
[1] 3.24
```

Looking into the code of `extract_numeric` gives us that it is a simple wrapper for `gsub`.

```
function (x) 
{
    as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "", as.character(x)))
}
```

So, for current example, you can use regular expression

```
gsub("[^0-9.-]+", "", test)
```

Comment: That works! However is there a solution that uses regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, '\\d.\\d+')
#[1] "3.24"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one

```
gsub("\\$", "", test)
```

If you are concerned only about numbers, then you can use

```
gsub("\\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)", "\\1", test)
```

If you want to remove `()` also, then use

```
gsub("\\(\\$(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\)", "\\1", test)
```